# How to keep i-node consistent across separate Filesystems

Tags: linux, mount, inode

So if i move a file from one directory to another within one Filesystem, say "/opt" which is a mounted point, the i-node of that file stays consistent as long as the files stays within that mount-point "/opt". Now, if I move that file to say, "/usr", which is a different mount-point, the i-node of that file changes. Is there a way to keep the i-node of a file consistent when moving the file across filesystems?

Answer (score 3):

no - the inode is "assigned" by the filesystem (i.e., driver within the kernel).

In theory (using some low-level tool), you *could* write onto a specific inode, but in practice you would really not want to do this (too much work and too much chance of breakage).

A while back, I worked with someone who had the (not) bright idea of using inode numbers as unique identifiers for files.  That came to an end when considering how to restore a backup.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Haha, how did inodes affect the way of restoring backups?

Comment: They did not find it possible to restore the files with the same inode values (due to the nature of the application, using `dd` to save a raw device was not considered).

Comment: Ohh, haha. So the recovery backup was removed from the system right? Then inserted back in?